# How to pass a function of an object from a function inside a function of the same object?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Mouthful. Ok so this is the sample.
I need to pass bar1 from bar2 inside a function.

```
var foo = {
   bar1 : function () {

   }, 

   bar2 : function () {
      return function () {
        // bar1(); pass bar1 through here ... this.bar1 ? 
      }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save this in variable like this:

```
var foo = {
   bar1 : function () {

   },
   bar2 : function () {
      var self = this;
      return function () {
        self.bar1();
      }
   }
};
```

or use bind:

```
var foo = {
   bar1 : function () {

   },
   bar2 : function () {
      return function () {
          this.bar1();
      }.bind(this);
   }
};
```